Encode encoding argument failed: PostgreSQL `INTERVAL` does not support nanoseconds precision with Rust SQLX
I'm trying to perform an insert statement using the Rust SQLX crate. One of the datatypes I am trying to insert for one of the columns has the Rust type chrono::Duration.
This is a type which has nanosecond precision, which is a greater precision than the timestamp type which is supported by Postgres.
On the Postgres side, the column is of type interval.
The Rust code which I am using to try and insert this data looks like this.
let duration = chrono::Duration::from_std(std::time::Duration::from_secs(10));

let query_result =
    sqlx::query("insert into table_name (duration_column) values ($1)")
    .bind(duration)
    .execute(&executor);


Can you link to the Rust docs for the exact from_secs you're calling? I don't see it at https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/type.Duration.html and I also don't see the std::chrono at all that's in your answer.

@JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I'm half asleep. I messed it up. I've fixed it now

Those still don't seem to exist. Also, I found that error in sqlx, and it only triggers if value.as_nanos() % 1000 != 0, but for std::time::Duration::from_secs(10), it is 0.

@JosephSible-ReinstateMonica which function are you missing? And which Rust version are you compiling with?

Never mind, it was me being blind that time. But I still can't seem to reproduce this. Does assert_eq!(chrono_duration.num_nanoseconds().unwrap() % 1000, 0); fire for you? And is the real use a hardcoded 10 seconds, or is it calculating a time somehow?

@JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Yes sorry, I messed up the calculation as well. I will edit it. In short, use .num_microseconds().unwrap(). This is an i64, which has a maximum value of 106 million days.

I have found a slightly strange solution. I am not sure if this is the intended use of these APIs.
let chrono_duration = chrono::Duration::from_std(std::time::Duration::from_secs(10));

let mut duration = sqlx::postgres::types::PgInterval::default();
duration.days = chrono_duration.num_days();
duration.microseconds = chrono_duration.num_microseconds().unwrap();

// or

let duration = sqlx::postgres::types::PgInterval {
    months: 0,
    days: 0,
    microseconds: chrono_duration.num_microseconds().unwrap(),
}

